# WordPress – Display Posts whose Title Starts with a Certain Letter

Tags: php, wordpress, loops

I'm working on a WordPress site, and I'm having trouble querying posts that start with a certain letter.

This is what I am trying to accomplish:

[image: This is what I am trying to accomplish.]

Using a simple loop such as:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<h2>Library</h2>

<ul class="library-grid">

<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post'
    );

    $post_query = new WP_Query($args);

    if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
      while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <li class="library-item">
            <img src="<?php the_field('poster') ?>" alt="<?php the_title() ?> poster" class="library-poster">
            <div class="library-item-footer-diagonal"></div>
            <div class="library-item-footer">
                <h3 class="library-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title() ?></h3></a></h3>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" class="more-info-button">More info</a>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php
      }
    }
?>
</ul>

<?php
get_footer();
```

I get all posts:

[image: I get all posts.]

**How do you think I could edit the loop to get only posts whose title starts with a certain letter?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
   if($post_query->have_posts() ) {
      while($post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $post_query->the_post();

        if(get_the_title()[0] != "a") continue; //so it only shows titles starting with lower case a
        ?>
```

this is case sensitive, if you want you can  `strtolower()` the_title() and your letter

if you want to loop throught the alphabet, you can loop through 97 to 122 which is the ascii for the lowercase alphabet and use [`chr()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.chr.php) to convert it to a letter

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working… WordPress echoes only the titles when I add this.

Comment: it's because the_title() prints it , i've update to use get_the_title() try it out, I should also point out that this is VERY inefficient a much more efficient way would be to order the query and output the HTML in an alphabetical list